# win7 magnifier keyboard shortcuts deactivation

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, magnifier

I'd like to get rid of win7 magnifier keyboard shortcuts but use magnifier. I tried to find an option in magnifier's options for deactivating keyboard shortcuts to no avail.

Comment: Are you talking about the Win+(+/-) (plus/minus sign) shortcuts?